# Flutter images in GitHub repo

Tags: flutter, image, github, assets, gitignore

In the assets folder of my flutter project I have a .gif and a .png that I'm using for things like loading screens and app icons. It looks like flutter is automatically generating different versions of these images and placing them into subfolders of the android folder, iOS folder, etc. They are not being caught by the gitignore automatically created by Android studio.

Is this correct, or do I need to update my gitignore so these files are not being uploaded?

Google research only shows me references to the automatically created gitignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need commit this files too because all platform-specific (splash and launcher icons is platform-specific) should be stored in repository (and you don't need to generate them each time when you open a clear project). If you won't place this images to VCS - you can't build an app (because on native side you have links to new generated files).

Files in assets is a resources that are Flutter using only on their side (in regular cases).